# My datetime2 comparison doesnt work where string does

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime2

I get desired result back for the following statement.

```
select * from xx where  yyy='2014-05-17 19:00:00.2000000';
```

Why do i get no results back when i run?

```
DECLARE @NowDateTime datetime2(7) ='2014-05-17 19:00:00.2000000';
select * from xx where yyy= @NowDateTime
```

Comment: What's the type of `yyy` column?

Comment: Is the desired result=no result?

Comment: No the desired result is a few rows, i get nothing back (and no error) when using the variable

Comment: Could you please add your underlying table structure.  I just ran this example on my box and was not able to duplicate the problem.  Changing the precision to a lower yielded more results.  Leaving it at 7 produced a single result for my example.  And using a mismatched data type like DATETIME just threw a conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with EF LINQ select having a parameter datetime2, while the column was datetime
The issue probably was with datetime vs datetime2 rounding as described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108287/why-does-my-query-search-datetime-not-match).

We resolved the issue by altering the column datatype to datetime2.

```
alter table xx alter column yyy datetime2
```